# Quantifiers. Translate english statements into Symbolic Form.

Tags: quantifiers

***1. All natural numbers are Integer.***

So I know natural number is N and integer is Z but how do I translate this statement into Symbolic Form ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

$$\forall x\in\mathbb N\space\space\space x\in \mathbb Z$$

Comment: It is either $\forall x~(x\in\Bbb N\to x\in\Bbb Z)$ xor $\forall x{\in}\Bbb N~x{\in}\Bbb Z$.  Do not mix and match.

Comment: But what's wrong with the "$\implies$" above? I read the above as "For all natural numbers x, it implies that $x$ is an integer", that is all natural numbers are integers.

Comment: An implication requires an antecedant and a consequent; both of which are well formed formula on there own. The quantifier binding of a variable cannot act as an antecedant as it is not in itself a well formed formula.

Comment: Likewise, a well formed quantified statement has a variable binding and a scope which must contain a well formed formula.  A statement that begins with an implication symbol, such as: ${\implies}x{\in}\Bbb Z$ , is not a well formed formula. @Äres

Comment: A formula beginning with a quantifier is called a quantified formula. The statement above does not begin with $\implies x\in\mathbb Z$. The statement $ \forall x \in A \Rightarrow  x \in B $ means that every element in $ A $ is also an element of $ B.$ Anyway, I've fixed my answer. Thanks.

Comment: A quantified statement has two components: the variable declaration, and the scope over which it is bound. The scope comes after the declaration and must be a well formed formula.  Your declaration is $\forall x\in A$ and thus the *scope* contains $\implies x\in B$ and is thus not well formed.